# implement a SOAP client in python from WSDL

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to use a SOAP web service in python. but I did not find any decent python soap client library for this job. libraries like Zeep are too elementary and does not support complex security policy.

I was searching the internet for days with no success. I will really appreciate your help.

after failing to find a good Python client I decided to implement my own client but the Ws-* protocol
is too complex! (especially the security parts), there are thousands of the spec pages!, so I lost (in fact the problem is not the WS-* protocol itself, yes it is complex, but one has to read other related specs such as XML Signature, Encryption ...).

I know if I re-read the specs I will eventually be able to understand it and implement the library but I have no time left.

here is some of the WSDL of the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="....." targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
    xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"
    xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WS2007HttpBinding.....">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:TransportBinding
                    xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:TransportToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:HttpsToken/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic256/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Strict/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                        <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:TransportBinding>
                <sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens
                    xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:BootstrapPolicy>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:SignedParts>
                                            <sp:Body/>
                                            <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                                            <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                                            <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                                            <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                                            <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                                            <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                                            <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                                        </sp:SignedParts>
                                        <sp:EncryptedParts>
                                            <sp:Body/>
                                        </sp:EncryptedParts>
                                        <sp:TransportBinding>
                                            <wsp:Policy>
                                                <sp:TransportToken>
                                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                                        <sp:HttpsToken/>
                                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                                </sp:TransportToken>
                                                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                                        <sp:Basic256/>
                                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                                <sp:Layout>
                                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                                        <sp:Strict/>
                                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                                </sp:Layout>
                                                <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                                            </wsp:Policy>
                                        </sp:TransportBinding>
                                        <sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                                            <wsp:Policy>
                                                <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                                        <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                                </sp:UsernameToken>
                                            </wsp:Policy>
                                        </sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                                        <sp:Wss11>
                                            <wsp:Policy/>
                                        </sp:Wss11>
                                        <sp:Trust13>
                                            <wsp:Policy>
                                                <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
                                                <sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
                                                <sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
                                            </wsp:Policy>
                                        </sp:Trust13>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:BootstrapPolicy>
                                <sp:MustNotSendAmend/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:SecureConversationToken>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
                <sp:Wss11
                    xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                    <wsp:Policy/>
                </sp:Wss11>
                <sp:Trust13
                    xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
                        <sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
                        <sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Trust13>
                <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

can someone briefly explain to me how to talk to this service?

as far as I know, there are 5 (or 4?!) policies that all have to be used. I think I need to use the `<sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>` first to obtain a token! then use that token in the subsequent requests.

Comment: I think you have the wrong programming language for this. Python's support for SOAP is "basic". If you need WS-Security then you will have to learn about those policies the web service is using, and implement them by hand, or use some other tools (like Apache CXF in Java, or WCF in dot.NET) that you can then wrap in a simpler API that you can call from your python code.

Comment: the client wants it in Python